# Nativescript getViewById from ViewModel

Tags: mvvm, viewmodel, nativescript

I am used to get the TextField using `getViewById()` to apply [native android filters](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.LengthFilter.html) to it. How can I do this from ViewModel without breaking the rules of the MVVM architecture?

Comment: What is an native android filter? Google wasn't able to tell me that.

Comment: I was not clear with that, sorry... meaning this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.LengthFilter.html

Comment: And this is where I started. This works https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1338
I need this same behavior but from viewModel

Comment: I still don't see the necessity for this approach. Why don't you simply set `maxLength="20"` - or `maxLength="{{ yourVMvalue }}"` respectively - in on the TextField the view XML?

Answer (score 2):

*You cannot access the TextField from the ViewModel without breaking the MVVM pattern.*

Anyway, I would advice you to just call `getViewById()` from ViewModel to set native android filter functionality, since the [MVVM implementation of NativeScript](http://nativescript.github.io/nativescript-style-guide/#chapter1.0) is not designated solving this problem. You doesn't have to fear that this is bad practice at all.

Comment: Any example code how do I get view from ViewModel since I only get crashes.

Comment: Are there any exception messages of your crashes? can you provide them please?

Comment: I figured out what to do. On navigatedTo(args) I got var page = args.object; then I got var myTextField = page.getViewById("myTextField"); I passed this reference to my viewModel by calling viewModel.someFunction(myTextField); Then from viewModel I can use this myTextField reference and do what ever I need, in this case set anroid.setFilters...